# Serial port '/dev/diag' does not exist in my Galaxy phone

Tags: qualcomm, rooted-device, dm

I have a rooted Galaxy SM-A52 Mobile phone (Android 14) based on Qualcomm Snapdragon chipset. I connect to my phone using adb and run the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/diag
```

But '/dev/diag' port does not exist. I need to connect to this port to get Qualcomm QXDM diag message. How I can enable '/dev/diag' port? How I can connect to it?